# Trying to calulate days off based on a persons shift pattern

Tags: c, telerik

I am trying to find timeslots for people of sick or off on holiday and block out times in a telerik scheduler component the problem i am having is with mutlple resources instead of just highligting the one person off its hlighing for all them

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the TimeSlotCreated event of the apertureAppointments control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="TimeSlotCreatedEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
 protected void apertureAppointments_TimeSlotCreated(object sender, TimeSlotCreatedEventArgs e)
 {
        int i = 0;
        bool isFound = false;
        List<tblApertureNetShiftPattern> _list = new List<tblApertureNetShiftPattern>();
        _list = _dal.getHolidays();
        List<Resource> resources = new List<Resource>(apertureAppointments.Resources.GetResourcesByType("Managers"));
        Resource res = resources[5];

        foreach (tblApertureNetShiftPattern sp in _list)
        {
            if (_list.Count > 1)
                i++;
            else
                i = 0;

            DateTime? dt1 = _list[i].startdate;
            DateTime? dt2 = _list[i].endDate;
            if (sp.manager_name == "Adam Adair" && res.Text == "Adam Adair")
            {
                isFound = true;
                if (DoDateRangesOverlap(e.TimeSlot.Start, e.TimeSlot.End, dt1, dt2) && isFound == true)
                {
                    e.TimeSlot.CssClass = "UnavailableCssStyle";
                    dt1 = null;
                    dt2 = null;
                    isFound = false;
                }
            }
            else if (sp.manager_name == "Clare Coyle" && res.Text == "Clare Coyle")
            {
                if (DoDateRangesOverlap(e.TimeSlot.Start, e.TimeSlot.End, dt1, dt2) && isFound == false)
                {
                    e.TimeSlot.CssClass = "UnavailableCssStyle";
                }
            }
            else if (sp.manager_name == "Christine Clarke" && res.Text == "Christine Clarke")
            {
                if (DoDateRangesOverlap(e.TimeSlot.Start, e.TimeSlot.End, dt1, dt2) && isFound == false)
                {
                    e.TimeSlot.CssClass = "UnavailableCssStyle";
                }
            }
            else if (sp.manager_name == "Conan Keenan" && res.Text == "Conan Keenan" && isFound == false)
            {
                if (DoDateRangesOverlap(e.TimeSlot.Start, e.TimeSlot.End, dt1, dt2) && isFound == false)
                {
                    e.TimeSlot.CssClass = "UnavailableCssStyle";
                }
            }
            else if (sp.manager_name == "Susie McCormick" && res.Text == "Susie McCormick")
            {
                if (DoDateRangesOverlap(e.TimeSlot.Start, e.TimeSlot.End, dt1, dt2) && isFound == false)
                {
                    e.TimeSlot.CssClass = "UnavailableCssStyle";
                }
            }
        }
 }
```

For which there is only one entry Adam Adair but instead its highling all the cells for the person who is off.

Get holidays just returns a list of items.

```
 public List<tblApertureNetShiftPattern> getHolidays()
 {
        List<tblApertureNetShiftPattern> list = new List<tblApertureNetShiftPattern>();

        var q = from _holidays in apertureNetEntities.tblApertureNetShiftPatterns.Where(w => w.isDeleted == false && w.isOff == true)
                select _holidays;

        list = q.ToList();

        return list;
 }
```

There is only one record and its for admam adair to be off

Comment: Dont just down vote give an explanation as to why ? ! I have showed what the problem is and what I have tried so far so what exaclty is wrong !

Comment: You are required to give an explanation as to here on meta http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this myself without much help from the community in the end was simple i was not checking the timeslot created statement for the text of the person as well.

```
if (res.Text == "Adam Adair" && e.TimeSlot.Start == dt1 && e.TimeSlot.Resource.Text == "Adam Adair")
```

The important addition here is e.TimeSlot.Resource.Text == "Adam Adair"